# Can you push in dist files from a local non github directory using git into a certain directory of a github repositiory?

Tags: git, github

For example:

I want to take the files of local dist folder ('built' app files) and `push` it to a folder within one of my github repositories. ie. github.com/myacct/repositoryA/app

I was looking to do something like

```
cd path/to/my/local/localdevproject/dist    // not git repo
git init
git push origin https://github.com/myacct/repoA.git/app
```

I tried it and it gives an error saying wrong refspec. Tried reading the docs from git about it and they are confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the working tree temporarily to another folder (which includes your `dist` folder)

```
cd /local/path/of/your/repository/clone
git --work-tree=/path/to/parent/of/dist add dist
git mv dist folder1
git commit -m "Add dist to folder1"
git push
```

The main command in that solution is `git --work-tree`, that allows to change the working tree path (while, here, keeping the git-dir to the current repo).
See [`man git` page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git).

Comment: Okay that sounds like a possible way to work it. Let me try/digest that a few times.  Thanks in the mean time.